# Toggle Button has a loading error

Tags: c#, picturebox, togglebutton

we wrote this code for switch(toggle) button. 
We're working with WindowsForm

```
int i=0;
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ++i; 

    if (i == 1)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\off.png"); 
    } 
    else if (i == 2) 
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\on.png");
        i = 0; 
    }
}
```

It works But we're seeing loading cursor.What can the reason?

[image: image size like this]

Comment: In whole form or just on picture box?

Comment: You ought to call `Dispose` in image when you don't need it.

Comment: maybe the picture size is big and its taking time to load the picture

Comment: Picture size is like this. (i added a picture to question)

Comment: a) I wonder if you were not better off with a regular Button, which can display an image as well.. b) for real code the images should be loaded from resources c) for testing, does the loading cursor also appear when you use: `pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "D:\\on.png";`

Comment: pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "D:\\on.png"; i used this code and it works

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be a possibility with how your code works, so let me give you a better piece of code that should do the trick and will be more efficient.

```
bool IsOn = true;

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(IsOn)
    {
      pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\off.png"); 
      IsOn = false;
    } else {
      pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("D:\\on.png");
      IsOn = true;
    } 
}
```

I hope this helps!

EDIT: I actually misread this completely, but please feel free to use the code above.

Make sure that both your files exist, as this sort of error suggests that the files don't exist.

Comment: I've tried the code. But the program still keeps on loading

Comment: Can you please upload a screenshot of the problem you are receiving?